# Почему переменную из localStorage не получается взять во всех скриптах в расширении chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для chrome. У меня есть переменная, которая изначально создаётся в файле background.js через localStorage.

background.js

```
if (localStorage.getItem('IsOn') === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('IsOn', 'true');
}
```

Она у меня отлично работает в файле popup.js т.е. если написать

```
localStorage.getItem('IsOn');
```

То функция спокойно отработает и вернёт 'true', если до этого переменная не была отредактирована, но если я хочу получить значение этой переменной в файле content_script.js, то функция возвращает null.

Как мне можно получить переменную с localStorage в файле content_script.js?

Вот так выглядит manifest.json

```
{
    "name":"SmartSiteBlocker",
    "description":"Blocks sites you don't wanna use",
    "version":"1.0",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":["<all_urls>"],
            "js":["jquery-3.5.0.min.js", "content_script.js"],
            "run_at":"document_end"
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["blocked.html"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я понял как это можно сделать без localStorage. Первым делом добавляем строчку в manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

Затем, чтобы создать переменную, например IsOn со значением true, нужно написать

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;
storage.set({ IsOn: true });
```

А чтобы получить её в другом скрипте, пишем

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;
storage.get('IsOn', function (items) {

});
```

Внутри функции эта переменная будет названа items.IsOn